# "About me" preview wrongly renders some Markdown

Tags: bug, profile-page, markdown, markdown-preview

When I edit the "About me" section on any of my accounts I see this:
[image]

Under the "About me" box we can see exactly what I would like to display in my "About me" sections.

But after saving changes and going to my profile, it looks like this:
[image]

I noticed it 3-4 months ago and thought it was a bug. As you can see the pictures are from Code Review but this is just an example. It happens on all of my accounts.
Why is this happening?

Comment: `=` under a line means header formatting in Markdown. Not a bug.

Comment: Well, the bug is that the preview shows something different than the actual outcome...

Comment: @Glorfindel might it not be the actual outcome that is incorrectly rendering the Markdown?  It shows it correctly in the preview, then the outcome shows it incorrectly.

Comment: @Glorfindel You are right. Maybe I should have been more persistent in that something feels wrong.  
The accepted answer is the correct answer regarding my original title and focus. But it's not sufficient enough to be accepted regarding the new title and focus of the question.  
What should be done in a case like this? Should I undo the acceptance? Would that draw more eyes to the problem?

Comment: Ohh I've just noticed @Ollie's [follow-up question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354281/question-and-answer-preview-is-wrongly-rendering-some-markdown). Then we are done with my question, aren't we?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An equal sign (`=`) under a line means header formatting in Markdown (see [Markdown Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)).  You need to remove the `=)` at the bottom of your "About Me", it'll go back to normal.  Although the preview is still showing something that is different from what it looks like when you visit your profile, so it's still a bug.

Comment: Well, this turned out to be embarrassingly simple... I would have sworn the text had been the same before I noticed the change, but I guess it had not been the same after all. Also, the preview is not messed up by the emoticon, so it didn't occur to me to tweak the text.

Comment: Isn't this still a bug in that the markdown renderer used by the preview is not rendering the same as the backend renderer? I would thing what you see in the preview is what you get when you save changes.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I tested it in my answer:  The same bug applies to answers, and questions too I presume.

Comment: @KodosJohnson see [my bug report for more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354281/question-and-answer-preview-is-wrongly-rendering-some-markdown).

Comment: Markdown was changed not long ago, which also broke existing formatting.