# Question and answer preview is wrongly rendering some Markdown

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown, markdown-preview

As you know, an equal sign (=) under a line means header formatting in Markdown (see [Markdown Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), for those who don't).  The text below:

## Example

has one `=` underneath it, but with a `=)` it looks like this in the preview:

[image]

and renders as this in the actual outcome:

## This example has a `=)`!

With a `=)`, the actual post should show the same as the screenshot above, but it shows the same as though it had only one `=` under it.  Why does the preview show something different than the actual outcome, and why does it render with the `)`?

---

**UPDATE:**

The same thing is happening with the dash:  `-`, it renders also with a `-)` underneath.  Example:

### This example has a `-)`.

It actually happens with any *one* character after either the `-` or `=`, and that includes characters in other languages (I've been testing this by editing my "About Me").

Comment: Yes, it’s [very inconsistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349027/289905). It seems that the rendered post matches `/^\s*[=-]+.*$/m` as header formatting (the “underline” line), whereas the preview matches something like `/^\s*[=-]+\s*$/m`. The number of dashes or equal signs never matters. The “rendered post” output even clashes with list formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for raising this. I've been able to reproduce and agree that it should be consistent between the preview and the actual post content. We'll dig into any discrepancies related to Markdown preview as a first place to look.

That said, this isn't high priority for us, it might take some time to address. I've added it to our backlog and will have the team respond here when we revisit this.

Comment: Given the rollout of the new editor, I think it's important that all bugs reporting differences between the rich text preview and the actual rendered post should receive higher priority. It doesn't look very good to see a post that looks just as you like it in the new rich text preview only for it to suddenly change once the edit is saved.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog You're right - it didn't occur to me to bundle this with changes to the new editor. I've attached this to the work we've prioritized there. That being said, I still want to set expectations: we're still gathering feedback on the new editor and there may be more pressing changes to address before we revisit this.