# Bullet lists beginning with empty first bullets render correctly in the preview, but not on the actual post

Tags: bug, markdown, list

It displays correctly in the preview. [Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63876832)

[image]

On this input:

```
* 
* John
* 陳大文
```

I get the following (as shown in the above screenshot):

*

- John
- 陳大文

Comment: If this is a bug with markdown, please [edit] the question and show us the markdown that you used.

Comment: @41686d6564 added

Comment: Related: [Question and answer preview is wrongly rendering some Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354281/289905#comment1183996_354281) and [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349027/289905).